# Good upper-bound for $\mathbb E_A[e^{-t\|A\|_2}]$, for $t\ge0$ and random m by n matrix with iid entries with law $N(0,1)$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $A$ be a random $m$-by-$n$ matrix with iid $N(0,1)$ entries, $m$ and $n$ large with $n/m \longrightarrow \alpha \in (0, 1)$ . Let $\|A\|_2$ be the largest singular value of $A$  (i.e the spectral norm of $A$) and let $t \ge 0$.

> **Question.** What is a good upper bound for $\mathbb E_A[e^{-t\|A\|_2}]$ ?

Comment: I've attempted to make the title identical to the body.  I've also added details about the size of shape of the matrix. Hope you're fine with the current version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability distribution of the largest singular value of $A$ (or the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $AA^T$) is derived in [Distribution of the largest eigenvalue for real Wishart and Gaussian random matrices and a simple approximation for the Tracy–Widom distribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3394). There are exact answers for finite $n,m$ and asymptotic forms for large $n,m$. From here finding the desired average of $e^{-t\lambda_1}$ is a matter of quadrature.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the reference. At the moment, I also came across this reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2990.pdf. A little twist: largest singular value of A is the **square root** of the largest eigenvalue of $AA^T$.